# Script is not working in safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I have written a code to add script at run time but that code is not working in safari browser. My code is given below.

```
  var head = document.head;  
  var script = document.createElement("script"); 
  script.type  = "text/javascript"; 
  script.setAttribute("src", url);  
  head.appendChild(script);  
  head.removeChild(script);
```

Sorry for bad english...

Comment: Why do you remove the script on the end? Shouldn't you wait at least until it loads?

Comment: any errors in the javscript console?

Comment: Not getting any error in console. NOTE:- This is working fine in firefox, Chrome and IE-9

Comment: if you get no error from the console, then your code is working. But maybe it is not working the way you want it to? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: $.getScript('yourscript.js'); is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing an attribute by using it's name as a property doesn't work in all browswers afaik. So try to use:

```
  script.setAttribute('type', "text/javascript");
```

instead of

```
  script.type  = "text/javascript";
```

Or if you don't mind using jQuery which handles for you the crossbrowser issues, do it like this:

```
$.getScript('yourscript.js');
```

Comment: I tested on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.2 (14C109) w/ Safari Version 8.0.3 (10600.3.18) and it works fine. Single problem that I can see is that you're adding the script `head.appendChild(script)`, and then you're immediately removing it `head.removeChild(script)` -- is this intended?